# How would you write the word несватаная/несватанная/не сватаная/не сватанная?

Tags: прилагательные

There is a Russian song by a female pop band called "Fabrika". The song itself is called "Не виноватая я".
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zevEK3UhnQw

The refrain contains the word "(не)свата(н/нн)ая) which is either **несватаная**, **несватанная**, **не сватаная** or **не сватанная**.

But how do you write (не)свата(н/нн)ая and which rules must one apply? (I consider the rules to be super extra hard but we can't change them.) More specifically, I mean how you would write down the refrain of the above mentioned song.

> Мама, ну не виноватая я, не виноватая я
>
> Что вот осталась я одна така не сватанная
>
> Не виноватая я, не виноватая я
>
> Все говорят — любовь нагрянет вдруг негаданная.

[link](http://www.megalyrics.ru/lyric/fabrika/nie-vinovataia-ia.htm)

Let me share my thoughts however:

1. Firstly, I am sure **с-** in **сватать** is not a prefix. The word "сватать" is completely unrelated to **вата**.
2. Secondly, we must determine the aspect of the verb. (Since there are prefixless words like пущенный, купленный, брошенный, решённый etc.). I decided to consult a few dictionaries. They unanimously told me that сватать is imperfective. Что делать? — сватать. "Отец упорно не хотел сватать свою дочь за первого встречного". Не хотел что делать? For comparison: что сделать? — посватать или сосватать — if you have a prefix (**по-** or **со-**), then it's perfective.
3. Thirdly, I even consulted [this link](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/).
   Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. — М.: Эксмо, 2006. — 480 с.
   §99.

> Исключения (к § 98–99). Пишутся с нн  вместо н  : а) прилагательные
> желанный, жданный и (в составе устойчивых сочетаний) виданное ли
> дело?; слыханное ли дело? Они образованы от глаголов несовершенного
> вида желать, ждать и видать, слыхать. Особые случаи: прилагательные
> надёванный и (в составе устойчивого сочетания) разливанное море; они
> образованы от приставочных глаголов несовершенного вида надевать,
> разливать, т. е. от глаголов с суффиксом −ва, которые закономерно не
> образуют страдательных причастий прошедшего времени; б) прилагательные
> с приставкой не : неведанный, невиданный, негаданный, нежеланный,
> нежданный, ненадёванный, неожиданный, неслыханный, нечаянный и (в
> составе устойчивого сочетания) недрема́нное око; в) сложные
> прилагательные долгожданный, доморощенный и (в составе собственного
> имени) Андрей Первозванный. Вторые части этих приставочных и сложных
> прилагательных также соотносятся с глаголами несовершенного вида.

Taking in consideration everything I've previously sayed, I would probably stick to one Н in the suffix and, logically, would probably write **несватаная**. Still some doubts though because the hyperlink I've provided think it must be a double Н.
Again, essentially my question is about the rules. What rules apply in my situation?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant excerpt from the song lyrics to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question and clarified it. I provided a blockquote which contains the refrain. Finally, added a hyperlink to a site where you cand find the lyrics of songs, including "Не виноватая я".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сватанный
св'атанный; кратк. форма -ан, -ана

Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.

There is no adjective, only the participle страдательное причастие,
which can have an agent of the action, i.e. you can ask the question  *by whom?* — не сватанная кем? (If it were an adjective, this question would be impossible — just compare неприспособленный человек).

Раздельно пишется не с причастиями , имеющими при себе зависимые слова. «Одна така(я) не сватанная».
http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56

Comment: Are you sure the participle has dependent words in this sentence? For me, both одна and така depend on the pronoun я, not on (не)сватанная. Compare «я один такой неучтенный»

Comment: Agree with @J-mster, несватанная can be removed completely, or more adjectives can be added, there is nothing that depends on it in this sentence.